# Limit the amount of results from mySQL conditionally?

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my query:

```
SELECT * FROM Photos WHERE Event_ID IN ($eventidstring)
```

I know I can limit the total amount of results from this query using LIMIT 5

**I need the Limit the amount of results Per value in $eventidstring.**

**So if $eventidstring = 23,41,23***

***And there are 10 results WHERE Event_ID = 23, I want to limit this amount to 5. The same for all the other values in $eventidstring.**

Comment: Please show table definition - CREATE TABLE statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may have some joy doing something similar to Oracle's RANK by PARITION in MySQL.

Sadly this feature is not available in MySQL though you can work around it using [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3162389/multiple-ranks-in-one-table/)

Dump that in an inline view and then select those rows with rank <= 5;

Hence:

```
SELECT t.* FROM (
SELECT ( 
        CASE Event_id 
        WHEN @curEventId 
        THEN @curRow := @curRow + 1 
        ELSE @curRow := 1 AND @curEventId := Event_Id END
      ) AS rank,
      p.*
FROM      Photos p INNER JOIN (SELECT @curRow := 0, @curEventId := '') r
ORDER BY p.Event_Id DESC
) t
WHERE t.rank <= 5 ORDER BY t.Event_Id asc;
```

Consider how you are going to 'choose' the top five by Event_Id too. You can always add in more after the `ORDER BY p.Event_Id DESC` to decide this.

Comment: Fantastically. This is incredible

Answer (score 1):

I take it you're writing that query somewhere inside your PHP, so you need to split the `$eventidstring` into it's component values, form a SELECT for each and UNION all after the first one.

You sould do this with a loop of some sort, and concatenate the query strings in the loop...

Comment: Yes that seems like my only solution besides the one above

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly and you want to get *five of each*, you can use this:

```
(SELECT * FROM Photos WHERE Event_ID = 23 LIMIT 5)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM Photos WHERE Event_ID = 41 LIMIT 5)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM Photos WHERE Event_ID = ... LIMIT 5)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe with a SELECT UNION but you need a new select for each value:

```
SELECT * FROM Photos WHERE Event_ID = 23 LIMIT 5
UNION SELECT * FROM Photos WHERE Event_ID = 41 LIMIT 5
UNION SELECT ...
```