# SQL IF STATEMENT with PHP variable

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I am trying to make a single query with SQL conditions like the above:

Let's say first that we have the PHP variable `$reco` that will let us update the data when we want:

```
mysql_query("
INSERT INTO app_table (views, average)
VALUES
(
IF($reco = 'yes', '$views', views),
IF($reco = 'yes', '$aver', average)
)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
views = IF($reco = 'yes', $views, views),
average = IF($reco = 'yes', $aver, average)
");
```

The problem is that `$reco` doesn't works as I want inside the query but a column of table will work, so how can make it work with a PHP variable?

For example if I had reco inside the table would work like this:

*Notice that I have the $reco in php variable not inside the table.*

```
mysql_query("
INSERT INTO app_table (views, average)
VALUES
(
IF(reco = 'yes', '$views', views),
IF(reco = 'yes', '$aver', average)
)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
views = IF(reco = 'yes', $views, views),
average = IF(reco = 'yes', $aver, average)
");
```

Comment: It's really hard to tell what the problem and/or question is. And that is besides the fact I tried to find the above query.

Comment: what's in `$reco`? If it's something like `blahblahblah`, and you don't have a `blahblahblah` field in your table, then the query is  going to blow up on you. `mysql_query(...) or die(mysql_error())` will tell you exactly WHERE/how the query's failing. That or you're totally not understanding how PHP and SQL operate...

Comment: I don't understand the question either

Comment: start with seperating the php and mysql

Comment: Guys, the $reco is 'yes' or 'no' php variable string and i am saying for example in "IF($reco = 'yes', '$views', views)" if $reco is 'yes' make views = '$views' else leave views as views ($views -> php, views -> sql colum)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if it's kind of a proof of the principle, and you still want to do it on the SQL side:

```
$query = "... IF('$reco' = 'yes', '$views' ...";
```

Note the quotes around $reco. So, if $reco were 'yes' the query would be interpreted as `... IF ('yes' = 'yes', 'some_value' ...`

Comment: har-wradim many thanks, it will be a pure string inside the sql query, i am searching this for hours and my mind don't went there! Thanks!

Comment: Don't forget to up-vote the answer and/or mark it as the accepted one, if you like :). I want to stress it again: it's just a general principle useful in some situations, but I wouldn't do it this way in your particular case (if I understand it correctly).

Comment: I can not vote because i dont have enough reputation, but i have another question, how to make if condition to include limit or not? like: $query = "SELECT **** FROM **** WHERE **** GROUP BY **** ORDER BY **** DESC IF(some_condition) LIMIT ***** END IF;

Comment: It's not straightforward, but you can try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7899639

Comment: Thanks i found a solution to do this with IF(A,B,C)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way, I think, is to do your string comparison purely in PHP:

```
if ($reco == 'yes') {
   $views = $views_value;
   $average = $average_value;
}
else {
   $views = $views_default;
   $average = $average_default;
}

//escape your $views and $average strings, if necessary
$query = "INSERT INTO app_table (views, average) VALUES ('$views', '$average') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE //whatever";
```

Comment: Thanks har-wradim this was my original code and dont forget to get views and average inside else statement i need a select query so the code becomes bigger but i am trying to short it as i am changing the code often.

Comment: Actually this way you perform string comparison only once. If you do it the way you proposed: it's done 4 times (on the SQL side)

Comment: Yes i know, but i wanna do it as i want short code and this way i am escaping from make a Select query to get views or average. Actualy the query is more more bigger and this way it will be shorten