# SQL SELECT Columns From Multiple Tables Without Repeating Data

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to query 2 tables using the following sql statement in an attempt to return all records from each table that contains a specific id.

```
SELECT Phone.Phone, Email.Email FROM Contacts.Phone, Contacts.Email 
WHERE Phone.ContactId = :contactId AND Email.ContactId = :contactId
```

`Contacts.Phone` table contains 2 phone numbers for the given id and `Contacts.Email` contains 1 email for the given id. Using the above sql query, I get the following rows returned. This is just an example, of course, of a situation in where my result set from each table does match in number of rows.

```
Row 1: 555-555-5555 - email@email.com
Row 2: 666-666-6666 - email@email.com
```

The email is repeated in order to fill in the second row when I am trying to get:

```
Row 1: 555-555-5555 - email@email.com
Row 2: 666-666-6666 - NULL
```

I think I need to use a `UNION` to somehow join the tables, but I can't figure out exactly how to write the sql statement. Another option would be to perform 2 separate SQL queries, which would be easier but I figure performance wise it would be better to collect all data I need in one query.

I am using MySQL.

Comment: I think you need to `LEFT JOIN` the Email table.

Comment: @ryandlf You have 2 (or more) phone numbers for one Contact Id, and can have 2 (or more) emails for a one Contact Id?

Comment: I think you'd want to use two subqueries, each with some variant of ROWNUM/rank/row_number, and perform a full outer join on that field. For a specific query, you'd have to tell us what RDBMS you're using (MySQL? Oracle? SQL Server? PostgreSQL? something else?). That said, I think your statement that "performance wise it would be better to collect all data I need in one query" is misguided. One query that pulls *n* rows is better than *n* queries that each pull one row, but there's no reason to combine two logically-separate queries into one.

Comment: Yes, I am building a contacts database and the idea is dynamic phone numbers, emails etc so for each contact I add to my database I can have as many phone numbers as I want (home, work, mobile etc) as with email, addresses etc. That is why I have them separated into their own tables and use a foreign id to connect them with the intitial Contacts table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I think this:

> Another option would be to perform 2 separate SQL queries, which would be easier but I figure performance wise it would be better to collect all data I need in one query.

is a bit misguided. The performance difference between one complex query and two simple queries will be quite small. That said, you suggested using a `UNION`; if you do want to use a single query, you can do this:

```
SELECT 'EMAIL', Email.Email
  FROM Contacts.Email
 WHERE Email.ContactId = :contactId
UNION ALL
SELECT 'PHONE', Phone.Phone
  FROM Contacts.Phone
 WHERE Phone.ContactId = :contactId
 ORDER BY 1 -- put e-mail addresses before phone-numbers
;
```

The first column will return the "type" of result, and the second column will have the datum.

Comment: Thanks. For me this approach actually works a little nicer than returning nulls because I can check the first column and place the data accordingly. Just so I understand, the order by is simply saying Order by table 1, correct? Is there a specific reason to return the email data first?

Comment: @ryandlf: You're welcome. `ORDER BY 1` actually means "order by the first field" (in this case the "type" field). The only reason to put e-mail first is that I figured it would be nicer to get all of one and then all of the other, and `'EMAIL'` sorts before `'PHONE'`. If you want phone numbers first, you can do `ORDER BY 1 DESC`. If you don't care about the order at all -- if you're O.K. with potentially getting (say) some e-mail addresses, then some phone numbers, then some more e-mail addresses -- then you can just drop the `ORDER BY 1` completely.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `left outer join` to solve your problem, the query would look sonething like this if you were using MS SQL:

```
SELECT 
    Phone.Phone, 
    Email.Email 
FROM 
    Contacts.Phone 

Left Outer Join Contacts.Email ON Phone.ContactId = Email.ContactId
```

Your results will look like the following:

```
Row 1: 555-555-5555 - email@email.com 
Row 2: 666-666-6666 - NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really wanted the results in two columns with NULLs for repeated data, then it would really help if MySQL supported the `RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ...` syntax that some other DBMS systems allow. Regrettably it does not, but Daniel Vassallo has come to the rescue by describing how it can be done in MySQL in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3162389/multiple-ranks-in-one-table/).

Adapting his approach to your situation:

```
SELECT Phone.Phone,
    CASE Email.Email
    WHEN @curEmail THEN NULL
    ELSE @curEmail := Email.Email END AS Email
FROM Contacts.Phone, Contacts.Email, (SELECT @curEmail := '') AS r
WHERE Phone.ContactId = :contactId AND Email.ContactId = :contactId
```

When I ran this on the test data in your question, I got:

```
Row 1: 555-555-5555 - email@email.com
Row 2: 666-666-6666 - NULL
```

which is the desired result.