# how to give number to occurrence in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to give number to occurrence in sql result
for example I have table like this:

```
ID| Name | Login Date
1 |John  | 12/1/2013
2 |John  | 15/1/2013
3 |Ben   | 12/2/2013
```

Now I want additional column to know what times they log in:

```
ID| Name | Visit times
1 |John  |1
2 |John  |2 
3 |Ben   |1
```

Comment: which rdbms are you using? oracle, mysql,sql server ..?

Comment: You need count based on Name?

Comment: In the second example you show John twice? Why do you need that?

Comment: @aweis I want to know how many times they log in, for example if John log in again now columns 'Visit times' will show '3'

Comment: @Dhinakaran normally it's some id but use Name is fine I just want to know how to give number of duplicate occurrence, I only know how to count it

Comment: @ginkun: how do you store the different login dates? if you only store let's say the most recent date they log in you don't have enough information in the db, right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  t1.ID
,       t1.Name
        (
        SELECT  COUNT(t2.ID)
        FROM    tablename AS t2
        WHERE   t1.Name = t2.Name
                and t2.ID <= t1.ID
        ) AS 'Visit times'
FROM    tablename AS t1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the example below.

```
create table log(id integer, name varchar(100), time datetime);

insert into log values (1, 'John', '2013-01-12 00:00:00');
insert into log values (2, 'John', '2013-01-15 00:00:00');
insert into log values (3, 'Ben', '2013-02-12 00:00:00');

SELECT  @row_num := IF(@prev_value=l.name,@row_num+1,1) AS RowNumber
       ,@prev_value := l.name
  FROM log l,
      (SELECT @row_num := 1) x,
      (SELECT @prev_value := '') y
  ORDER BY l.name, l.time DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

your problem has been solved in [this so post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3162389/multiple-ranks-in-one-table/).

adapted to your tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXIST staging_table (
      id
    , name
    , visit_sequence
)
    SELECT id
         , name
         , (
              CASE name
              WHEN @curType THEN @curRow := @curRow + 1 
                            ELSE @curRow := 1 AND @curName := name 
              END
           ) + 1 AS visit_sequence
         , login_date
      FROM your_table
         , (SELECT @curRow := 0, @curNamee := '') r
  ORDER BY name ASC
         , login_date ASC
;


ALTER TABLE your_table ADD visit_sequence INTEGER AFTER login_date;

UPDATE your_table yt
     , staging_table st
   SET yt.visit_sequence = st.visit_sequence
 WHERE st.id = yt.id
     ;
```