# How to add a column with auto-incremented values to a table of mySql database?

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table with the following structure-

```
  Col-1      Col-2     
(primary)

   234        A        
   154        B
   987        B
   374        C
   983        C
   364        C
   873        A
```

I've to insert a column, say **Col-3** to this table with auto-incremented values starting from 0, based on Col-2 value. For the above table I want the values to be like-

```
  Col-1      Col-2      Col-3
(primary)

   234        A           1
   154        B           1
   987        B           2
   374        C           1
   983        C           2
   364        C           3
   873        A           2
```

The table is static, so if possible, I want to run the query directly in *phpmyadmin*.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: How are `Col-3` values found?

Comment: You can set initial values like here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3162389/multiple-ranks-in-one-table/. Adding proper trigger should solve the problem of inserting new data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using correlated subquery.

```
SELECT  A.Col1, 
        A.Col2, 
        (
            SELECT  COUNT(*)
            FROM    tableName c
            WHERE   c.Col2 = a.Col2 AND
                    c.Col1 <= a.Col1) AS RowNumber
FROM    TableName a
ORDER   BY a.Col2, RowNumber
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a7d53f/2)

Comment: thanks a lot that's what I was looking for :D. One more thing, can you tell me the query to use, if I already have the Col-3 in the table and needed to update with the correct values.

Comment: @491243- Suppose I've `Col-2` in a `Table-2` associated with the `Col-1` of `Table-1`; what would be the query? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you need to join it. can you give sample records?

Comment: [Here are my tables](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6f3f5/2). Now, according to `B_ID` in `Table-2`, I want to update `DisplayOrder` of `Table-1` (both tables are linked with `A_ID`)

Comment: Err.. if for `234` it is `1`, then for `231` it should be `2`; since both have same `B_ID`. See, the display order should be acc to the `B_ID`; hope you understand ..

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible directly per your specification and will require a trigger which would set the value of Col-3 using `COUNT(Col-2)`. I think this would work, but test to be sure:

```
CREATE TRIGGER col2_count AFTER INSERT ON your_table
FOR EACH ROW SET col3 = COUNT(1) WHERE col2 = NEW.col2;
```