# Rank sql columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table like this:

```
+--------+--------+--------+
| color  | fruit  | amount |
+--------+--------+--------+
| red    | cherry |    124 |
| red    | plum   |     23 |
| green  | gauva  |    119 |
| green  | pear   |     14 |
| orange | orange |     23 |
+--------+--------+--------+
```

I want it to add rank like this.

```
 +------+--------+--------+--------+
 | rank | color  | fruit  | amount |
 +------+--------+--------+--------+
 |    1 | red    | cherry |    124 |
 |    2 | red    | plum   |     23 |
 |    1 | green  | gauva  |    119 |
 |    2 | green  | pear   |     14 |
 |    1 | orange | orange |     23 |
 +------+--------+--------+--------+
```

I need to rank it based on amount for each color (seperately). 
Is this possible ?

Comment: Is the ranking based upon the `amount` (for each `color`)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mysql rank function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333665/mysql-rank-function)

Comment: @Mureinik i need to rank based on two columns, rather than one column.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple Ranks in one table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3162389/multiple-ranks-in-one-table)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select
color, fruit, amount,
case when (if(@prev_color != color, @rank:=1, @rank:=@rank + 1)) is null then null
     when (@prev_color := color) is null then null
else @rank end as rank
from your_table
, (select @rank:=0, @prev_color := null) v
order by color, amount desc
```

Answer (score 1):

If the ranks are given based on the high `amount` of `color` availability, then you can also find number of rows less or more than with the `amount` value. That number of rows would be the `rank` for the concerned `color`.

```
select
 ( select count( color ) from fruits_table 
   where color = f.color and amount >= f.amount
 ) as 'rank',
 color, fruit, amount 
from fruits_table f
order by color, amount desc
-- order by field( color, 'red', 'green', 'orange' ), amount desc
;
```

You can alter the order of fields by `color` to show on top or bottom as desired using the `field` function. See the commented `order by` clause above.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT  @row_num := IF(@prev_value=o.Customer,@row_num+1,1) AS RowNumber
       ,colour
       ,fruit
       ,amount
       ,@prev_value := colour
  FROM Table1,
      (SELECT @row_num := 1) x,
      (SELECT @prev_value := '') y
  ORDER BY colour,amount DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a row number function where you specify where to start then numbering over (partition by) and how to organize the rows within that partition (order by.)

```
 | rank | color  | fruit  | amount |
 +------+--------+--------+--------+
 |    1 | red    | cherry |    124 |
 |    2 | red    | plum   |     23 |
 |    1 | green  | gauva  |    119 |
 |    2 | green  | pear   |     14 |
 |    1 | orange | orange |     23 |
 +------+--------+--------+--------+
```

```
select distinct 
  row_number() over (partition by color order by amount desc) rank,
  color,
  fruit,
  amount
from
  foo
order by
  color, amount desc
```

You will find that the row numbering starts over with each new color, and that within each color, the rows will be ordered by the amount sorted in descending order.

Comment: The question is tagged MySQL. However, this answer doesn't seem to be in MySQL.