# Sql Server Max() over partition by - translate into MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

So I've seen SQL Servers RowNumber() over(partition by id) convert to MySql from 
another question [posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3162389/multiple-ranks-in-one-table/)

But this doesn't help with another aggregate function such as MAX().

I need the Max() of a group of rows.

```
Cust_Type   Cust_Name   Revenue  Max
Top         A           10000    10000
Top         B           9000     10000 
Top         C           8000     10000 
Bottom      X           5000     7000
Bottom      Y           6000     7000
Bottom      Z           7000     7000
```

Now I know I can do a query to get the Max and Cust_Type and then join that to the whole table to add on the max value, but is there a way to not do that extra query but instead do it in the same fashion as the post I referenced?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, you could use user-defined-variables.

```
select cust_type, 
       cust_name,
       revenue,
       @max:=IF(@custtype!=cust_type,revenue,@max),
       @custtype:=cust_type
from yourtable, (select @max:=0, @custtype:='') t
order by cust_type, revenue desc
```

Comment: This is perfect. exactly what I needed.