# replace distinct nested values with ints

Tags: mysql

I have a nested tree of data in a table and I need to number them. It's easy to find the distinct values, get the row number and then use that, by I have a nested tree and need to do that for each level.

My table looks like this (I'm showing three levels, but I actually have four or more)

```
col1, col2, col3, some data cols ....
-----------------------------------
'AAA', 'AA', 'A', #####
'AAA', 'AA', 'B', #####
'AAA', 'AA', 'C', #####
'AAA', 'BB', 'D', #####
'AAA', 'BB', 'E', #####
'AAA', 'BB', 'F', #####
'BBB', 'CC', 'G', #####
'BBB', 'CC', 'H', #####
'BBB', 'CC', 'I', #####
'BBB', 'DD', 'J', #####
'BBB', 'DD', 'K', #####
'BBB', 'DD', 'L', #####
```

etc...

There is more data than that, and AAA represents some string, etc

What I need is for each distinct in col1, replace (or put in a new table) the values 1, 2, 3, etc

Then for each distinct in col1, find the distinct in col2 and replace with 1, 2, 3, etc. Repeat for col3.

To get something like this

```
col1, col2, col3, some data cols ....
   1,    1,   1, #####
   1,    1,   2, #####
   1,    1,   3, #####
   1,    2,   1, #####
   1,    2,   2, #####
   1,    2,   3, #####
   2,    1,   1, #####
   2,    1,   2, #####
   2,    1,   3, #####
   2,    2,   1, #####
   2,    2,   2, #####
   2,    2,   3, #####
```

Is this doable via a MySQL script?

I have the following which works wonderfully for Microsoft SQL server, and now need the same thing in MySQL, but can't find equivalent functions.

```
SELECT 
DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY col1) R1,
DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY col1 ORDER BY col1, col2) R2,
DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY col1, col2 ORDER BY col1, col2, col3) R3
FROM table
```

Comment: If you ask cryptic questions you run the risk of getting cryptic answers or none at all

Comment: How is this cryptic?  I have a solution provided by the exact same question for Microsoft SQL server which works wonderfully.  Now I need a solution for MySQL. I am not a strong sql programmer, and am trying to figure it out.

Comment: Take a look at this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3162389/multiple-ranks-in-one-table/

Comment: Some hints in that link (thank you), but his objective is quite different than mine. His is more like multiple ranks in a single data column. Mine is a nested rankings issue across multiple columns.