# Problems with Rank logic in MySql

Tags: mysql, rank

Having followed some examples posted in SO, namely this one, [Multiple ranks in one table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3162389/multiple-ranks-in-one-table/), I've attempted to apply this approach to my own situation, but I'm not getting the results I'm expecting. Here is my query:

```
  select r.memberid, r.final_rating,le.event_date, le.id, le.league_id,
(CASE r.memberid WHEN @curMember THEN @curRow := @curRow+1 ELSE @curRow := 1 AND @curMember := r.memberid END) AS rank
from rating r
inner join league_event le on r.league_event_id=le.id
inner join (SELECT @curRow := 0, @curMember := 0) x
where r.memberid IS NOT NULL
order by r.memberid, le.event_date desc, le.id desc
```

And here is the output:

[image]

What I'm trying to do is to group my records by memberid and then within those groups display the records in descending order by event_date and id (of the event). But what's apparently happening is that the rank keeps resetting within the set of a member's records each time the league_id changes even though I've not included league_id anywhere in my query other than the select clause. What the heck is going on here?

Comment: Could you please add a the structure and some test data for you tables? I have written my adapted approach but it's not tested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue when I used this approach on joined tables, so I had to adapt it. I use a subquery to build the desired output and apply rank calculation on the result:

```
SELECT rs.*,(CASE rs.memberid WHEN @curMember THEN @curRow := @curRow+1 ELSE @curRow := 1 AND @curMember := rs.memberid END) AS rank
FROM (
   SELECT r.memberid, r.final_rating,le.event_date, le.id, le.league_id
   FROM rating r INNER JOIN league_event le ON r.league_event_id=le.id
   WHERE r.memberid IS NOT NULL
   ORDER BY r.memberid, le.event_date DESC, le.id DESC
) rs, (SELECT @curRow := 1, @curMember := 0) x
ORDER BY rs.memberid, rs.event_date DESC, rs.id DESC
```